# Angular + Django: Sending POST request with cookies (CORS)

Tags: ajax, django, angular, cookies, cors

I'm developing an app using Angular for client side and Django for server side. During development I'm running Django in port 8000 for managing all API requests, and serving my client app using Angular CLI running at port 4200.

Sending GET requests to Django work w/o problems but when I try to send a POST request that includes some cookies with session information, it fails as the cookies are not included in the header.

I know that the source of this "problem" is the CORS issue [[read more here]](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b) and that it won't be a problem in production as both client and server apps will be running in the same server and port, however I wonder how can I fix this situation at least for development.

I've tried using the [django-cors-headers module](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) with the options `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS`and `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` set to `True` but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I managed to make all work.

I thought it was a problem of Django so I installed django-cors-headers module, however the "problem" is in the browser (actually is not a problem, it is a security issue, see [here][1]).

Anyway, I solved the problem using a **proxy rule** for my Angular CLI, as follows:

- First, instead of sending my requests to *http://localhost:8000/api/...*, I send them to */api/* (i.e. to my Angular server running at port 4200).
- Then I added a file in my Angular project called "proxy.conf.json" with the following content:

  `{
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8000",
      "secure": false
    }
  }`
- Finally, I added the flag "--proxy-config" to the Angular CLI server:
  `ng serve --watch **--proxy-config proxy.conf.json**`

Now, all API requests are sent to the port 4200 and Angular internally redirects them to Django, avoiding the CORS problem.

Note: With this solution I didn't need anymore the django-cors-headers module.